# The Verb »stoßen«

Tags: preposition, verb

> Ich habe mir den Kopf gestoßen. (gegen/an)
> Ich habe mir den Kopf angestoßen. (gegen/an)
> Ich habe mit dem Kopf an der Tischkante geschlagen.
> Ich habe mit dem Kopf auf der Tischkante aufgeschlagen.

Is there any nuances between these four examples? Is there a specific situation where we would use only one of them ?

Comment: When you ask a question in English you should also use an English title. Otherwise it is unclear in which language you are expecting the answer. The German word »stoßen« is not a noun, so it must not be written with an uppercase first letter. Your "three" examples are actually four. I corrected these errors and changed formatting of the examples.

Comment: For what it's worth: "Ich habe mit dem Kopf an der Tischkante geschlagen." means something like you tapped a beat with your head on the table's edge. While this is certainly possible, I'd at least describe this as unusual.

Comment: No, not even. Mit etwas stoßen an der Tischkannte means you played billard with your head as the queue and had to play a move close to the border, for example.

Answer (score 3):

There are different sentences with different meaning:

a) (sich) (an etwas) stoßen: to stumble or bump against sth. It implies usually no blood being spillt.

> Ich habe mir (ein Körperteil) gestoßen

This is unintentionally hitting something with the body part. Usually this is used when it hurts afterwards or leaves a sore spot visible afterwards.

b) etwas anstoßen

> Ich habe (eine Sache) (mit einem Körperteil) angestoßen

This means you hit something slightly, giving it a push. This is usually to describe an action on the thing and does not look so much at your body part used to push it.

c) aufschlagen: to bash sth open. this means you hit your bodypart with some blunt object or impact so badly that you are bleeding.

> Ich habe mir (ein Körperteil) (an etwas) aufgeschlagen

d) schlagen: to beat or hit

> Ich habe mit (etwas / einem Körperteil) an etwas geschlagen

You use the bodypart to beat (onto) something or hit or bang on something.